# c++ regex date search?

Tags: regex

Is following the correct way of matching a date format of: yyyy-mm-dd

```
std::regex e("\\d{4}[-]\\d{2}[-]\\d{2}");
```

The date cold be in brackets, i.e. (yyyy-mm-dd]

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: `[-]` is unnecessary (character set with one character); use this for terseness `-`.

Comment: It is enough, just after it use [`strptime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/strptime.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use word boundaries `\b` (in order not to match "dates" in strings like `1022015-12-233333`) with your regex, and then validate the dates with [`strptime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/strptime.html):

```
\\b\\d{4}[-]\\d{2}[-]\\d{2}\\b
```

Here is an [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/pBPsRG):

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct tm tm;
    time_t t;
        string data("On 2015-12-23, the shop will be closed, but on 2016-01-03, it will be open. Invalid date: 2016-13-32. ID: 1022015-12-233333.");
        std::regex pattern("\\b\\d{4}[-]\\d{2}[-]\\d{2}\\b");
        std::smatch result;

        while (regex_search(data, result, pattern)) {
            if (strptime(result[0].str().c_str(), "%Y-%m-%d", &tm) != NULL) {
              std::cout << result[0] << std::endl;
            }
            data = result.suffix().str();
        }
}
```